# C++ Encrypt Char with a Key and Mask

Tags: c++, encryption, codeblocks

I need to write a code which encrypt a char with a special key.
I must use own key and mask with XOR operation. 
But I have a problem with understanding and implementation of this.

Firstly, I created my own key which I use to encrypt a char. This key is e.q number: 123456789. In binary representation number 123456789 is: 00010101 11001101 01011011 00000111. I divided this to 4 x 8 bits because I enter a type of char. 
I must use this to encrypt my char with a mask too. My mask is 0xFF because it resets the oldest bits and the youngest 8 bits are left to operate with XOR operation. 
It means when I enter char "a" it should encrypt this with this key and a mask with XOR operation.

What's more, I wanted to check what my compilator shows with key[0] position. It means I have "int key[0] = {00000111}" As I think it should show a number of 7 as a binary number, but compilator shows number 73. Why?

I would appreciate if somebody can help me to resolve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void encryption(char chars[], const int size);

int main() {
    const int size1 = 4;
    char chars1[size1];
    unsigned int keys = 123456789;
    int key[] = {00000111}; // why does it show number 73 instead of 7 ?

    cout << "Enter a char to encrypt: " << endl;
    cin >> chars1[0];


    return 0; }

void encryption(char chars[], const int size) {
    unsigned int keys = 123456789;
    unsigned int key[] = {00010101, 11001101, 01011011, 00000111};
    unsigned int mask = 0xFF;
    int temp[4] = {0};


        temp[0] = chars[0] ^ (keys & mask);
        temp[1] = chars[0] ^ ((keys >> 8) & mask);
        temp[2] = chars[0] ^ ((keys >> 16) & mask);
        temp[3] = chars[0] ^ ((keys >> 24) & mask);

}
```

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, of course. But I am just a beginner and in my class we had simple example to use own key. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. `unsigned int keys = 123456789` is in hex `075bcd15`
   `00010101, 11001101, 01011011, 00000111`  is in hex `15cd5b07`
   While both are 4-bytes notice the reverse order of the bytes, that is because the computer used what is known as little-endian byte order for integers. So if you get the bytes by casting to an unsigned character you will get the reversed byte order from what you expect.
2. `unsigned int key[]` is an array of `int` which seem to be 32-bits (4-bytes).

For a single `unsigned int` use
`unsigned int keyBytes3 = {0x075bcd15};`

For an array of 4 `unsigned char`:
`unsigned char keyBytes[] = {0x07, 0x5b, 0xcd, 0x15};`

Personally for instances where size matters I prefer using `uint32_t` and `uint8_t` types, then it is clear of the sizes, `int` may be larger or smaller the 32-bits depending on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler does not interpret your `00000111`as binary. C++ 11 does not support binary literals. In addition, any number that starts with 0 (aka `00000111`) as the most-significant digit is considered to be in octal. In octal, `111` is the equivalent of `73` in decimal.

You'll need to convert all of your "binary values" to decimal, then use those. Or you could use [boost, which has a utility that handles what you're looking to do.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY)

Comment: There is hex and that is a lot closer to binary than decimal. 00010101, 11001101, 01011011, 00000111 -> 15, cd, 5b, 07.

Comment: Then that's a hexadecimal literal, still not a binary literal.

Comment: Never said it was? But OP wanted to use a binary literal, so my answer reflects that.

Comment: @zaph  Thank you for this informations, But Did I write it with correct implementation? Can I connect this temp[0], temp[1].. to one array?